# Azure AD bearer Token in header to authenticate request to web API - Problem with update method

Tags: reactjs, azure, bearer-token

May I know how we UDPATE record with bearer token. Below is my code of Service.js and authProvider.js. Rite now, it authorizes the API but doesn't update the record. When I inspect in Dev tools, the Request Method shows 'GET' instead of 'PUT' for update. Whereas my GET method (authFetch with GET) works fine though (I am able to retrieve record from the database with authorization). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

service.js:

```
 export async function getItem(ItemNo) {
    return await authFetch(config.apiBaseUrl + `/item/${ItemNo}`, 'GET');
 }

 export async function updateItem(ItemNo, data) {
    return await authFetch(config.apiBaseUrl + `/item/${ItemNo}`, 'PUT', data);
 }

authProvider.js:

import { MsalAuthProvider, LoginType } from 'react-aad-msal';

//authFetch will return fetch method with ID Token in Authorization header.
export const authFetch = async (url, method, body) => {
const token = await authProvider.getIdToken();
return fetch(url, {
    method: body,
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token.idToken.rawIdToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: method === 'PUT' ? JSON.stringify(body) : undefined
});
```

};

In the component:
FetchItem.js:

```
    async updateTutorial) {
    await updateItem(this.state.currentItem.itemNo,
        this.state.currentItem).then(
            (response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    response.json()
                        .then((responseData) => {
                            this.setState({
                                isLoading: false,
                                message: "Item updated successfully!"
                            })
                        });
                }
                else if (response.status === 401) {
                    throw new Error("User not authorized");
                }
                else {
                    throw new Error("Not working");
                }
            })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            this.setState({ isLoading: false, currentItem: 'Error: ' + err.message });
        });
}
```

Comment: You have hardcoded `GET` in your `authFetch` method. You would want to pass that as a parameter and also the request body.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please guide me on how to pass request body as parameter. I am new to react. I tried adding the below code to my fetchItem component.. const requestOptions = { method: 'PUT', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, body: JSON.stringify() };  and passed it as parameter to updateItem method but dint work as expected. I get an error saying "A non-empty request body is required".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try by changing your `authFetch` method to something like:

```
export const authFetch = async (url, method, body) => {
    const token = await authProvider.getIdToken();
    return fetch(url, {
        method: body,
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token.idToken.rawIdToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            //'Accept': 'application/json' // Add this line in addition
        },
        body: method === 'PUT' ? JSON.stringify(body) : undefined
    });
};
```

and then call them like following:

```
 export async function getItem(Serienr) {
    return await authFetch(config.apiBaseUrl + `/item/${ItemNo}`, 'GET');
 }

 export async function updateItem(ItemNo, data) {
    return await authFetch(config.apiBaseUrl + `/item/${ItemNo}`, 'PUT', data);
 }
```

Please note that the code above is untested so you may run into issues.

Comment: Thanks again, Your suggestion works perfect for 'GET'. It shows "TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': '[object Object]' is not a valid HTTP method" for PUT on the lines...  'await updateItem(this.state.currentItem.serienr, requestOptions,
        this.state.currentItem)' of fetchItem component and 'return fetch(url,' of authProvider.js

Comment: Like I said, it is untested code :). Can you edit your question and include the data that you're uploading?

Comment: I have added some code to give an idea of what I am doing. Update works fine without authorization, I face problem only when I use authFetch.

Comment: I believe the problem is with the following line of code: `await updateItem(this.state.currentItem.item, requestOptions,
        this.state.currentItem`. Can you try by changing it to `await updateItem(this.state.currentItem.item, this.state.currentItem)`?

Comment: I have tried that option, it still shows the same error "Failed to execute 'fetch". Also, I realize if I add 'PUT'  as parameter in the Service.js,  all fields in the page, gets empty while updating. If i am right, the state of currentItem is not being set.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact data you’re sending in your update request.

Comment: I have included the data I am sending. Problem should be either with the updateTutorial method or authFetch

Comment: Looking at the code in your question, your `updateItem` code is still not modified. It should be `export async function updateItem(ItemNo, data) {
    return await authFetch(config.apiBaseUrl + `/item/${ItemNo}`, "PUT', data);
 }`.

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned earlier, when I add 'PUT' in updateItem, I get "TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': '[object Object]' is not a valid HTTP method" on the lines... 'await updateItem(this.state.currentItem.serienr)' of fetchItem component and 'return fetch(url,' of authProvider.js. And all the fields in the page gets empty when i press update(data should stay put in general).

Comment: Discovered another typo in here: `fetch(url, {
    method: body,`. It should be `fetch(url, {
    method: method,`. Can you please try after correcting this? This would explain the error you're getting.

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks a lot for your time. I truly appreciate it :)

Comment: Fantastic! I am glad to hear that. All the best.